# Hybris 30 days license expired

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, license-key, licenses.licx

Im running my developer Hybris instance and I got a message the my license has expired.

Acoording to the wiki it saids I have to reinitialize database to continue my work

```
*** LICENSE VERIFICATION HAS FAILED! *** 

************************************************************* 
Your demo/develop license has expired, it is valid only for 30 days. If you're using develop licence you need to reinitialize database to continue your work. ************************************************************* 
Hybris licence [licence.advancedsecurity.true;licence.clustering.true;licence.date.2013.03.27;licence.email.support@hybris.com;licence.endcustomer=hybris AG;licence.eulaversion=2.0;licence.expiration.;licence.highperformance.true;licence.id=000001-001;licence.name=hybris Demo Licence;licence.version=5.0;]
Shutting down hybris registry.. 
archiving 1 old GC log files to log\solr\instances\default\archived 
archiving 1 console log files to \log\solr\instances\default\archived 
Rotating solr logs, keeping a max of 9 generations
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983 
Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching! 
error notifying tenant listener : ListableBeanFactory must not be null java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ListableBeanFactory must not be null 
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors (BeanFactoryUtils.java:308) 
at de.hybris.olatform..mx.MBeanRe•isterUtilities.refreshMBeans MBeanRe•isterUtilities..ava:157
```

This is the regular message.

This Hybris licence is only for demo or develop usage and is valid for 30 days.
INFO After this time you have to reinitialize database to continue your work.
INFO Remaining days ====> 26

**How do I continue my work without reinitializing ?**

Answer (score 13):

You can install temp license.

```
./license.sh -temp CPS_MYS
```

You will get 90 day temp license with above command. You need to remove existing temp license before installing new one with below command.

```
./license.sh -delete SystemID HardwareKey SoftwareProducts
```

You can get parameters which are used in above command with below command.

```
./license.sh -get
```

Sample commands given for MySQL on Linux/Mac,you need to use bat extension for windows.

Other license option is updating users create date with SQL:

```
UPDATE users set createdTS = NOW()
```

Source: http://gunce.mkysoft.com/install-hybris-temp-license/

Answer (score 5):

To solve this, you can install a temporary license.

### To install a temporary license

1. Remove `installedSaplicenses.properties` from the license folder

   ```
    \hybris\config\licence
   ```
2. Go to Platform directory and run the ***./license.sh-temp CPS_SQL*** or ***license.bat -temp CPS_SQL***

Follow [how-to-install-temp-hybris-license](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/07/how-to-install-temp-hybris-license.html) if you are using DB other than HSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Hybris gives you 30 days licence for dev/trial version. If you are getting licence expiry error after 30 days of your trail version, you can either initialize your system (only if this is your local database not the production one.), as this will erase all your data and licence will be reset.

Otherwise if you don't want to loose data then you just need to modify created timestamp and modified timestamp of users table in your database and set it to current date time. This will increase licence expiry by another 30 days.

command to change users table for extended hybirs (dev/trail) licence is as below.

**(Mysql)**

```
***update users set modifiedTS='2019-04-15 12:00:00',createdTS='2019-04-15 12:00:00';***
```

**(Oracle)**

```
***update "<database-name>"."USERS" set modifiedTS='17-APR-17 04.05.38 AM',createdTS='17-APR-17 04.05.38 AM';***
```

2019-04-15 12:00:00  --- This is the date of writing this answer. Please provide current date and time here.

read more about hybris [here](https://hikex.com)

Comment: By udating the modifiedTs in User table , I am able to extend the license. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to do using a query.

```
update users set modifiedTS='2020-02-20 12:00:00',createdTS='2020-02-20 12:00:00' where createdTS is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Hybris comes with the default 30 days trial license but using the below command you can extend it,
Go to the platform folder and paste the below command for windows user,

license.bat -temp CPS_SQL

[command in the platform folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwUCD.png)

Answer (score 0):

We need to create temp license by db.
for mysql: CPS_MYS

```
./license.sh -temp CPS_MYS

./license.sh -delete SystemID HardwareKey SoftwareProducts
 
./license.sh -get
```